# Javascript library to apply CSS for old browsers

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if such a javascript library exists to do the following:

1. Look at what CSS stylesheets are included on the page
2. Look at the browser to see if it supports selector XYZ on the stylesheet.
3. If not, use jquery to apply said style manually.

I am wanting such a library because throughout my site I am using `tr:nth-child(odd) td` to apply alternating row colors on tables. I can use jquery to apply these colors, but it would be nice if I could just include a library instead of duplicating my CSS in javascript everywhere.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child

Comment: @MattBall I know what I can and cannot use. However jquery allows you to apply these styles with its built in sizzle selector engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into using [**Selectivizr**](http://selectivizr.com/).

> Selectivizr is a JavaScript utility that emulates CSS3 pseudo-classes
>   and attribute selectors in Internet Explorer 6-8. Simply include the
>   script in your pages and selectivizr will do the rest.

Using this, you will have support for the `nth-child` selector, amongst various other pseudo/attribute selectors in IE6 through to IE8.

If you're already using a JavaScript library such as jQuery or Mootools, it's as simple as including the script. **[Here is a tutorial](http://blog.reybango.com/2010/09/08/start-using-css3-pseudo-classes-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8-using-the-selectivizr-javascript-library/)** for reference sake.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at modernizer
http://modernizr.com/

I think its what you are looking for.

Comment: Modernizr will only feature detect but **not** polyfill (as mentioned in 3.)

Comment: That library will not do what the OP is asking for in #1 and  #3

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/using-modernizr-to-detect-html5-features-and-provide-fallbacks/ I think it provides a way to do it